# Getting System.Security.SecurityException while sending file using JSON string with HTTPWEBREQUEST

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# plugin ( CRM 365 on premise) that will pass certain data along with a file  using JSON String with HttpWebRequest, this plugin works fine with file that is smaller than 26 kb, but will throw  System.Security.SecurityException without even execute the plugin code when file is around 26 kb or bigger.

If I serialize the string into JSON object, it doesn't work either. 
If I convert the data string into BYTE Array, it will hit the web service and return a data type not correct error.

Any advice will be very much appreciated.

**ERROR:**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.Security.SecurityException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #6DF5358FDetail:
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="">www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">schemas.microsoft.com/.../Contracts">
<ActivityId>bce3c532-ae6e-46a2-ab7c-9b069a56a312</ActivityId>
<ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="">schemas.datacontract.org/.../System.Collections.Generic" />
<Message>System.Security.SecurityException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #6DF5358F</Message>
<Timestamp>2019-10-31T19:15:46.7828725Z</Timestamp>
<ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
<ExceptionSource>PluginExecution</ExceptionSource>
<InnerFault i:nil="true" />
<OriginalException>System.Security.SecurityException
at System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectCloneHelper.GetObjectData(Object serObj, String&amp; typeName, String&amp; assemName, String[]&amp; fieldNames, Object[]&amp; fieldValues)
```

**CODE:**

```
var request = requestParams.ContainsKey("entityid")
? (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"{configurations.ServiceUrl}/{functionName}")
: (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"{configurations.ServiceUrl}/{functionName}?{requestData}");

request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.SendChunked = true;
request.TransferEncoding = "utf-8";
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;


String recordID = requestParams["RECORDID"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\\\"");

String DocumentFileName = requestParams["DocumentFileName"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\\\"");

var objAttachedDocument = entity.Attributes[requestParams["attributename"]].ToString().Replace("\"", "\\\""); ;


var valData = "{ \"RECORDID\": " + recordID + ", \"DocumentFileName\": \"" + DocumentFileName + "\", \"objAttachedDocument\": \"" + objAttachedDocument + "\"}";
localContext.Trace(valData);

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
sw.Write(valData);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()
```